# Escaping single quote in questDB using Python3

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2, questdb

I'm trying to insert a row with a string containing a single quote symbol into a QuestDB table. I tried using the following code below as well as the following SQL query using the console. Both gave me the same error: "')' expected".

INSERT INTO 'cpe_list' (mystring) VALUES ('o''brian');

```
import psycopg2

connection = psycopg2.connect(user='someuser', password='somepw', host='127.0.0.1', port=8812, database='mydb')
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (mystring STRING)")
sql_query = "INSERT INTO 'mytable' (mystring) VALUES (%s);"

cursor.execute(sql_query, ("o'brian",))



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testSql.py", line 9, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql_query, ("o'brian",))
psycopg2.DatabaseError: ')' expected
LINE 1: INSERT INTO 'mytable' (mystring) VALUES ('o''brian');
```

The above code is based on psycopg2 2.9.3 documentation on query parameters: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html?#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I verified it and this seems to be a bug. I created an [issue on Github to track it](https://github.com/questdb/questdb/issues/2309)

In the meantime, you could always use the ILP protocol (Python example available at [the QuestDB docs](https://questdb.io/docs/develop/insert-data/#examples))

There is also an upcoming QuestDB official Python client that should make ILP ingestion much more convenient, but still to be released.

Answer (score 0):

Just came to say QuestDB just released a new version which contains the fix https://github.com/questdb/questdb/releases/tag/6.5.3

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug I think, see docs.

Comment: How is this contributing anything to the question, after https://stackoverflow.com/a/73892387/7733418 Nothing in this extremely short post is not already covered by the info given there.